# How to set input field validation in reusable custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to make a reusable custom directive that will validate date in input field. Code provided below is working, however is not reusable at all which is my biggest concern. 
What I was trying to do, was to set a new scope in directive however I got an error:

> Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.

So I guess isolated scope is not going to help me.

Any other solutions?

**That's my first template:**

```
<form ng-submit="add()" name="addTask" class="form-horizontal">
  <input name="dateInput" is-date-valid type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="task.DueDate" datepicker-options="datepicker.options" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'UTC' }" uib-datepicker-popup="mediumDate" is-open="isOpened" required>
</form>
```

**That's my second template:**

```
<form ng-submit="edit()" name="editTask" class="form-horizontal">
  <input name="dateInput" is-date-valid type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="task.DueDate" datepicker-options="datepicker.options" ng-model-options="{ timezone: 'UTC' }" uib-datepicker-popup="mediumDate" is-open="isOpened" required>
</form>
```

**And that's my custom directive:**

```
function isDateValid($log) {
  'ngInject';
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
      var validation = can_i_get_this_from_controller ?

        if (validation) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('validation', true);
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('validation', false);
        }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = isDateValid;
```

Comment: You can try to use `ctrl.$setValidity('validation', value);` in your case.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash: Thanks, this part now works. Could help me with validation variable? How can I get it from ngModel controller? I would like to receive `true` or `false`.

Comment: I think, you should not get it from controller, but put this validation logic inside the directive. Btw, try avoid using $watch, this is not a good practice to use for validation - take a look at @madhur answer, his approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

The way you implemented the custom validator is not good, you should be doing something like this -

```
.directive('dateValidate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$validators.dateValidate = function(modelValue) {  
               //Your logic here, return true if success else false
           }
        }
    };
 });
```

It can be used on both form paths, so no need of that logic here.
To know more about these this is one good [resource](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/10/16/working-with-validators-and-messages-in-angularjs.aspx)